# AngularJS repeat HTML content based on Dropdown selection number

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have drop down to select a number. 
Based on the selected value I need to repeat the sections in html. 
For example if I choose 3 in the drop down then the page should display

```
Display section 1 of 3
Display section 2 of 3
Display section 3 of 3
```

Please help to figure out how I can achieve this. Your time and help is greatly appreciated. 
**Java Script:**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("SolutionCtrl", function SolutionCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.noOfSites = 0;
    vm.updateSites = function() {
      console.log(vm.noOfSites);
    }
    vm.getTimes = function(n) {
      return new Array(n);
    }
  })
```

**html:**

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="SolutionCtrl as ctrl">
      <div>
        <h5>Select No of Sites:</h5>
        <select ng-model="ctrl.noOfSites" ng-change="ctrl.updateSites()">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat = "t in ctrl.getTimes(ctrl.noOfSites) track by $index">
        <h2>Display section {{t}} of 3 </h2>       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

[**JSFiddle:**](https://jsfiddle.net/mlaksv/mnaxp5nz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working Fiddle**:  https://jsfiddle.net/mnaxp5nz/6/

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h5>Select No of Sites:</h5>
        <select ng-model = "noOfSites" ng-init = "noOfSites = 0" ng-change = "updateSections();">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat = "section in sections">
        Section {{ $index + 1 }} of {{ sections.length }}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

**Script**

```
<script>

  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.sections = [];

    $scope.updateSections = function () {

      $scope.sections = [];

      for (counter = 1; counter <= $scope.noOfSites; counter++) {

        $scope.sections.push(counter);

      }

    }

  });  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> just add the angularjs script file in your script it is working for me
>   try below one:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("SolutionCtrl", function SolutionCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.noOfSites = 0;
    vm.updateSites = function() {
      console.log(vm.noOfSites);
    }
    vm.getTimes = function(n) {
      return new Array(n);
    }
  })
</script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="SolutionCtrl as ctrl">
      <div>
        <h5>Select No of Sites:</h5>
        <select ng-model="ctrl.noOfSites" ng-change="ctrl.updateSites()">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat = "t in ctrl.getTimes(ctrl.noOfSites) track by $index">
        <h2>Display section {{t}} of 3 </h2>       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("SolutionCtrl", function SolutionCtrl() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.arr = [];
      vm.noOfSites = 0;
      vm.updateSites = function() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= vm.noOfSites; i++) {
          vm.arr.push(i);
        }
      }
      vm.getTimes = function(n) {
        return new Array(n);
      }
    })
</script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="SolutionCtrl as ctrl">
      <div>
        <h5>Select No of Sites:</h5>
        <select ng-model="ctrl.noOfSites" ng-change="ctrl.updateSites()">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="t in ctrl.arr track by $index">
        <h2>Display section {{t}} of 3 </h2> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: appreciate your help. Thank you..!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in GetTimes method that return array.

Please try below.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("SolutionCtrl", function SolutionCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.noOfSites = 0;
    vm.updateSites = function() {
      //console.log(vm.noOfSites);
    }
    vm.getTimes = function(count) {
      //return new Array(n);
      var ratings = []; 

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
    ratings.push(i) 
  } 

  return ratings;

    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="SolutionCtrl as ctrl">
      <div>
        <h5>Select No of Sites:</h5>
        <select ng-model="ctrl.noOfSites" ng-change="ctrl.updateSites()">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat = "t in ctrl.getTimes(ctrl.noOfSites) track by $index">
        <h2>Display section {{t+1}} of 3 </h2>       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
<div>
    <h5>Select No of Sites:</h5>
    <select ng-model="vm.noOfSites"  ng-options="durations for durations in vm.stories"></select>
</div>
    <div ng-repeat = "t in vm.getTimes(vm.noOfSites) track by $index" ng-show="vm.noOfSites">
        <h2>Display section <span data-ng-bind="$index + 1"></span> of <span data-ng-bind="vm.stories.length"></span> </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

script

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl(){
    this.stories = [1,2,3]
    this.getTimes = function(n) {
      if(n){
        return new Array(n);
      }
    }
});
```